# new objects do not appear in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have an arraylist of students and I am writing it to a text file in my save method and this is successful every time i run the application and it loads all of my objects the first time i run the program successfully. My problem is when I start the app again after closing and try to save and load new objects then it only loads my old objects from the first session and not any of the new saved objects.Save method is to write and load method is to read

```
package application;
import java.io.Serializable;
public class Student implements Serializable{
    
    
    private String name = null;     //students name
    private int ID = 0;             //students ID number
    private String DOB = null;      //Students Date of Birth
    
    
    public Student(String name,int ID, String DOB) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setID(ID);
        this.setDOB(DOB);
    }
    
    public void printStudent() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name + " ID: " + ID + " DOB: " + DOB);
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }
    public void setID(int iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }
    public String getDOB() {
        return DOB;
    }
    public void setDOB(String dOB) {
        DOB = dOB;
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + "    | ID:  " + ID  + "    | Date of birth:  " + DOB;
    }
}
```

---

```
package application;
    
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
public class Test extends Application {
    
    
      ArrayList<Student> arraylist = new ArrayList<Student>();          //arraylist of student objects
      Student student;
      
      Student line;
      Validation validation = new Validation();
      
     
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
        
            primaryStage.setTitle("MTU Student record system");
            
            
            
            Label enterNamelbl = new Label("Enter Student Name");
            TextField enterNametxt = new TextField();
            HBox hbox1 = new HBox(42,enterNamelbl,enterNametxt);
           
            hbox1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            
            Label enterIDlbl = new Label("Enter Student ID");
            TextField enterIDtxt = new TextField();
            HBox hbox2 = new HBox(70,enterIDlbl,enterIDtxt);
            hbox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            
            Label enterDOBlbl = new Label("Enter Student Date of Birth");
            TextField enterDOBtxt = new TextField();
            HBox hbox3 = new HBox(27,enterDOBlbl,enterDOBtxt);
            hbox3.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            
            Button addbtn = new Button("Add");
            Button removebtn = new Button("Remove");
            Button listbtn = new Button("List");
            HBox hbox4 = new HBox(12,addbtn,removebtn,listbtn);
            hbox4.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            
            
            TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
            HBox hbox5 = new HBox(textArea);
            
            
           
            Button load = new Button("Load");
            Button save = new Button("Save");
            Button exit = new Button("Exit");
            HBox hbox6 = new HBox(12,load,save,exit);
            hbox6.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
            
           
            VBox vbox1 = new VBox(29,hbox1,hbox2,hbox3,hbox4,hbox5,hbox6);
            vbox1.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
            
            
            //adding a student to the arraylist
            addbtn.setOnAction(e-> {
                
                validation.isInt(enterIDtxt, enterIDtxt.getText());
                String name = enterNametxt.getText();
                 int ID = Integer.parseInt(enterIDtxt.getText());
                 String Dob = enterDOBtxt.getText();
                 
                                        //validating user input
                Student student = new Student(name,ID,Dob);
                arraylist.add(student);
                System.out.println(arraylist);   //to remove later   
                 
                
            });
            
            //listing the arraylist of students
            listbtn.setOnAction(e -> {
                    textArea.setText(null);
                  for(Student stu : arraylist){
                      
                       textArea.appendText(stu + "\n");
                      
                      }
                
            });
            //removing a student
                removebtn.setOnAction(e -> {
                int ID = Integer.parseInt(enterIDtxt.getText());
                Student studentToRemove = null;         //temporary variable to store student obj   
                    for(Student student:arraylist){
                            if(student.getID()==ID);
                            studentToRemove = student;
                    }
                        if(studentToRemove==null)
                            System.out.println("No customer found");
                        else
                            arraylist.remove(studentToRemove);          //need to throw an alert here       
            });
            
                
            //saving everything to a txt file
                save.setOnAction(e ->{
                    
                    try {
                         File file  = new File("StudentData.txt");
                         //File to store student data
                         ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file,true));
                         os.writeObject(arraylist);         //writting all the items too the txt file
                         os.close();
                       }
                    
                    
                    catch(FileNotFoundException e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch(IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    
                });
                
           //load everything from the txt file
                load.setOnAction(e ->{
                    
                    try {
                        textArea.setText(null);
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("StudentData.txt");
                        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                        List<Student> students = (List<Student>) ois.readObject();
            
                         // for(Student stu : students){
                              
                               textArea.appendText(students + "\n");
                              
                             // }
                        ois.close();
            
                    } 
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                                    
                    catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                        
                
                });
               
            
            Scene mainScene  = new Scene(vbox1,500,500);
            //mainScene.getStylesheets().add("application.css");
            primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
            primaryStage.show();
            
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Application.launch(args);
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: this looks like plain java, that is unrelated to javafx - make sure that the save/read cycle is working in a plain java programm (hard-code some data) before going on to use with ui.

Comment: Most IDEs have the ability to [format code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#reformat_file), something you might want to try in your IDE.

Comment: don't canibalize your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems

**During Writing**

You are specifying

```
FileOutputStream(File,true)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) this will append data to your File so you are not actually adding data to your ArrayList but infact it will append multiple ArrayLists to your file so remove the boolean flag and write

```
FileOutputStream(file);
```

Which will overwrite the content of the file

**During Reading**

Due to your writing error you were only reading the first ArrayList written to your file the very first time you ever ran your application hence why you were getting only old data

After reading the ArrayList from your file in the load setAction code add that loaded data to your original ArrayList used by your application

```
arrayList.addAll(students);
```

Also objects written to files are not in text format so to avoid misleading people change the extension to something else for  the sake of clarity

Comment: Hi, I have done that but now it only prints the new objects and not the old ones

Comment: You have to delete your current text file and start over.  Data in that can't be saved

Comment: I delete the text file every time i retry.

Comment: "prints only new objects not old ones" have you added the loaded data to your ArrayList used by your application as I have said in the 2nd part of my answer?

Comment: I have fixed it the additional issue was when I was clearing my textarea prior to adding new data. Thank you for your help hopefully this answer helps someone else too